# htpasswd executable is missing

Tags: 13.10, apache2

I'm running 13.10.  Clean install.  Ran:
sudo apt-get install apache2

I would expect that I would have htpasswd in the /usr/sbin directory along with the apache2 executable.  I don't.

I can provide any info necessary.

Comment: Please split your question. `htpasswd` is covered here, while you could create a separate question with apache reinstall.

Comment: Also missing on 14.04

Answer (score 141):

Perhaps you have apache2-utils not installed.
Try searching apache-utils in software manager or with command line:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

Answer (score 10):

```
username@host:~$ htpasswd
The program 'htpasswd' can be found in the following packages:
 * apache2-utils
 * mini-httpd
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

The error message is obvious. `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils` should solve your problem with missing `htpasswd` binary.

Comment: Not if you uninstall that horrible 'command-not-found' package.